# SQLITE datetime function to display localtime doesn't work

Tags: sqlite, datetime, utc, dst, localtime

I have my Sqlite batabase with a Timestamp as Primary Key, this Timestamp is recorded as UTC. And I have checked that records are correct, according to my Timezone and DST.

I am trying to display these Timestamps in my app, but in Localtime format, for that I use the function: SELECT ... datetetime (timestamp, 'localtime').

But what I obtain is my localtime plus 1 hour, I don't know why.
The localtime in my computer is correct, I use Ubuntu 12.04 as OS.

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Comment: Do you use the years 1970 to 2037?

Comment: @Adam111p SQLite works for all years between 0000 and 9999.

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT datetime('now'), datetime('now', 'localtime');`?

Comment: The localtime_r() C function normally only works for years between 1970 and 2037. For dates outside this range, SQLite attempts to map the year into an equivalent year within this range, do the calculation, then map the year back.

These functions only work for dates between 0000-01-01 00:00:00 and 9999-12-31 23:59:59 (julidan day numbers 1721059.5 through 5373484.5). For dates outside that range, the results of these functions are undefined.

Comment: Which timezone are you in, and exactly which timestamps give you problems?

Answer (score 0):

Could this help you?

Caveats And Bugs

The computation of local time depends heavily on the whim of politicians and is thus difficult to get correct for all locales. In this implementation, the standard C library function localtime_r() is used to assist in the calculation of local time. The localtime_r() C function normally only works for years between 1970 and 2037. For dates outside this range, SQLite attempts to map the year into an equivalent year within this range, do the calculation, then map the year back.

These functions only work for dates between 0000-01-01 00:00:00 and 9999-12-31 23:59:59 (julidan day numbers 1721059.5 through 5373484.5). For dates outside that range, the results of these functions are undefined.

Non-Vista Windows platforms only support one set of DST rules. Vista only supports two. Therefore, on these platforms, historical DST calculations will be incorrect. For example, in the US, in 2007 the DST rules changed. Non-Vista Windows platforms apply the new 2007 DST rules to all previous years as well. Vista does somewhat better getting results correct back to 1986, when the rules were also changed.

All internal computations assume the Gregorian calendar system. It is also assumed that every day is exactly 86400 seconds in duration.

https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have it.
Yeah, the dates are "nowaday" days (after 2000).

I think the problem was that I have the timestamp in the DB as a string type, so when I make: SELECT datetime(Time,'localtime')... doesn't work properly because it has no tzinfo (is an unaware datetime).
So I get the correct time handling the data after SELECT (in my case with python):
1.- Get the data with simple SELECT query
2.- Aware the datetime in python to UTC timezone (using pytz libray)
3.- Convert then to local timezone (with localize and astimezone modules)